# Python NoneType exception ZMQ

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, nonetype

I am using pyzmq to transmit messages between a rrbroker.py and an reworker.py. For some reason I am getting

```
worker:
    Users/eric/Documents/Programming/JavaScript/NodeJS/urchin/urchin_worker.py in <module>()
        111 while True:
        112     try:
    --> 113         message = socket.recv()
        114         message = json.loads(message)#decode into JSON
        115         print message
    Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <zmq.core.socket.Socket object at 0x104ffc460> ignored
```

broker code:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
backend = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
frontend.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")
backend.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5560")

# Initialize poll set
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)
poller.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)

print 'starting Router-Dealer Broker...'
# Switch messages between sockets
while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll())
    if socks.get(frontend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        message = frontend.recv()
        print 'passing message from frontend to backend'
        print message
        more = frontend.getsockopt(zmq.RCVMORE)
        if more:
            backend.send(message, zmq.SNDMORE)
        else:
            backend.send(message)

    if socks.get(backend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        message = backend.recv()
        print 'passing message from backend to frontend'
        print message
        more = backend.getsockopt(zmq.RCVMORE)
        if more:
            frontend.send(message, zmq.SNDMORE)
        else:
            frontend.send(message)
```

broker log:

```
passing message from frontend to backend
???0{pK???+E?5??
passing message from frontend to backend

passing message from frontend to backend
{'foo':'bar'}//data from client (connected to the broker's router port).
```

conspicuously enough, my broker sends 3 requests at a time (this is normal) to the worker but the first packet seems to be gibberish, the second seems to be empty and the third finally contains the data I wanted to send in the first place.

So the broker sends off the packet, but it seems like the worker.py never receives the data.

Comment: The 'gibberish' is just the socket identity - a random bytestring. It will make more sense if you do `print repr(message)` instead of `print message`.  A few questions:  Can you post *complete* code?  What version of pyzmq / libzmq, and what OS?  How did you build/install pyzmq?  Is your worker using threads?  The `Exception...ignored` message is usually seen during process shutdown, when things are getting cleaned up.